# Cortex A9 secondary core boot failure

Tags: arm, boot, cortex-a

Running Altera ArriaV with dual core Cortex A9 in SMP mode. The second core wakes up at address `0x0` which contains the following instruction :

```
LDR pc, [pc, #2324]
```

I expect to find on the next step the core execution instruction on that (2324 or 0x918) address. What actually happens is that after the step PC contains `0xC` value. Something is wrong here. Can anybody help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: Did you take into account that `pc` will be `8` rather than `0`?

Comment: not, please explain

Comment: From the ARM ARM: *A2.3
ARM core registers [...]PC, the program counter
• When executing an ARM instruction, PC reads as the address of the current instruction
plus 8.
• When executing a Thumb instruction, PC reads as the address of the current instruction
plus 4.* ARM32 is a hilariously broken architecture that is horrifyingly burdened by the legacy of the ARM1 chip. It's less of a designed architecture and more of a specific microarchitecture turned specification.

Comment: thanks. that actually means that the lower 8 bytes of the memory cannot be used for code. correct?

Comment: No. You just have to subtract the extra `8` from the immediate. Or just use the `ldr pc, <label>` notation for the instruction.